# Blue/Black line appearing on exception thrown in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I'm having a problem with VS2005. Whenever I have an exception thrown and my program breaks, the line that it breaks on is not readable because it turns black and blue. Please see my screenshot for a better idea of what I'm talking about. [image]

I had resharper installed but I went ahead and disabled it but this is still happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more than just a color change.  The line is entirely overwritten with garbage.  Must be some other misbehaving add-in.  Verify this by running devenv.exe with the /SafeMode command line option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to reset your default settings for Visual Studio?  Sometimes settings can stick when you uninstall add-ons. Go to your Visual Studio command line, usually found in your VS Tools directory.

type

> devenv /ResetSettings

Restart VS and see if that clears up your color scheme issues.  Note this will reset all of your default settings, so only use it if you want the factory default for VS.

Comment: This didn't help. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few settings you should check in Tools-->Options-->Environment-->Fonts and Colors.

- Breakpoint (Error)
- Breakpoint - Advanced (Error)
- Breakpoint - Mapped (Error)
- Current Statement

If it's not one of these, you may have to go through the list and look for the Display Item that has the Item Background/Foreground set to what you're seeing, then change it to something that is more legible.